# In VS Code, how can I explicitly state the variable type for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code

I'm writing Javascript in Visual Studio Code.
I have some code like this:

```
let bankNumberVal = bankNumber.val();
let num = parseInt(bankNumberVal);
```

bankNumber is a jQuery<HTMLElement> and .val() returns string | number | string[].

At this point I get an error on the parseInt(...) line stating "Argument of type 'string | number | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'."

So, I need to tell VSCode that I KNOW bankNumberVal will return a string (something I could do in TypeScript). So I try this:

```
/**@type {string} */
let bankNumberVal = bankNumber.val(); 
let num = parseInt(bankNumberVal);
```

But I get the same error.

**Is there a way I can tell VS code to "cast" bankNumber.val() to a string? Or do I have to resort to using //@ts-ignore to get rid of my errors?**

Comment: Is the language mode (at the bottom right of the VS code window) set to Javascript or Typescript? Because since Javascript is loosely typed, VS code shouldn't complain if it's set to JS.

Comment: In typescript you can also `let bankNumberVal = bankNumber.val() as string;`  you can do that on the first line or on the second line when you pass it into the method.

Comment: I'm using Javascript (language mode at the bottom says Javascript). VS code complains because I have set "checkJs": true in my jsconfig.json. I like the tooling.

Comment: Call toString()? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString

Comment: @TiesonT. - That's exactly what I wanted. It's unfortunate that I couldn't come up with that myself. Thanks!